# rotation not in the middle

Tags: android, image-rotation

Why doees the bitmap not rotate in the middle?

When I rotate points with sin, cos it's o.k. and rotation in Swing with AffineTransform works but not with matrix rotation.

I use this code:

```
matrix.reset();    
  matrix.setRotate(35.0f,middleofx,middleofy);    
  Bitmap t=Bitmap.createBitmap(BI_auto);    
  Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(t, 0, 0,
  BI_car.getWidth(), BI_car.getHeight(), matrix, true);`
```

The rotation of the point works:

```
 sx = ((carx) + 45 - worldx);   
 sy = ((cary) + 45 - worldy);    
 float rad = (float) (grad / 180.0 * Math.PI);   
 float ex2 = (float) (sx + length* Math.sin(angle - rad));   
 float ey2 = (float) (sy + length* Math.cos(angle - rad));
```

The green and red points are correct in the red rect, but the green car rect is wrong and not in the middle.
Show the bitmap for the wrong rotation!

[image: car rotation]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about java syntax but you should do it like something below.

```
matrix.translate(-middleofx,-middleofy); // these might be positive.
matrix.setRotate(35.0f);
Bitmap t=Bitmap.createBitmap(BI_auto);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(t, 0, 0, BI_car.getWidth(), BI_car.getHeight(), matrix, true);
matrix.translate(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rotated bitmap is made bigger than the original to not clip the image. You could try drawing the result so that the coordinates of the center match.